# SGR reset code is ignored if \n is placed on a new line

Tags: ruby, linux

My problem is that if I have a string styled with a background SGR code, in this example `\e[41m` for a low intensity red background, and I use `\n` to create a new line, the red background expands and fills remaining line. However, this only happens if the line with a red background expands over one or more lines. This quirk is illustrated better here:

```
$ irb
2.2.1 :001 > require 'terminfo'
 => true 
2.2.1 :002 > SCREEN_WIDTH = TermInfo.screen_size[1]
 => 273 
2.2.1 :006 > string = "\e[41m"; (1).times{ string << 'x' }; puts "#{string}\e[0m\nI am reset"
x
I am reset
```

This works perfectly. One `x` appears on the screen with a red background around it and only that one `x`. The rest of its line is clear.

```
 => nil
2.2.1 :003 > string = "\e[41m"; (SCREEN_WIDTH / 2).times{ string << 'x' }; puts "#{string}\e[0m\nI am reset"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I am reset
 => nil
```

This works perfectly. Many `x`s appears across the screen with a red background around them and only them. The rest of its line is clear.

```
2.2.1 :004 > string = "\e[41m"; (SCREEN_WIDTH).times{ string << 'x' }; puts "#{string}\e[0m\nI am reset"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I am reset
 => nil
```

Here we're filling the entire line with `x`'s. `273` of them precisely fill the terminal window, as the terminal window is `273` columns wide, courtesy of `TermInfo.screen_size[1]`. This works perfectly. 273 `x`' fill the screen with a red background around them and only them. There is no "rest of line" here as there is no room, but I'm not seeing any unexpected effects.

```
2.2.1 :005 > string = "\e[41m"; (SCREEN_WIDTH + 1).times{ string << 'x' }; puts "#{string}\e[0m\nI am reset"
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
I am reset
 => nil
```

Here's where the bug comes into effect. If you add just one more `x` so that it is moved down onto the line below, this second line becomes filled with red, even though there is a SGR reset, `\e[0m` before the `\n`. It makes for some horrendous output and I want to stamp this behavior out.

Here's the result you can see for yourself:

[image: terminal]

You can see it better [here](http://oi61.tinypic.com/wam3ye.jpg), I think SO resizes the entire image so it can all fit inside the question box.

I'm running [gnome terminal](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-terminal/3.6.2-0ubuntu1) under [Ubuntu 14.04](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+milestone/ubuntu-14.04.3). I don't know if this is a terminal bug, a ruby bug, or a terminal bug pertaining to me installation...I did have to repair terminal a few months back.

Is this a known quirk when creating CLI's with Ruby? Is there a tried and tested way to stop it?

**TL:DR** Look at the third group of `x`' in that screenshot. How do I stop the second line of the third group being filled with red? I only want the first `x` of the second line of the third group to have a red background behind it.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by a broken-by-design misfeature called "background color erase" (bce), in all emulators that support this feature. In practice, graphical terminal emulators (`xterm` and clones, including `gnome-terminal` as you noticed; as described in TERM=xterm's corresponding terminal description file) have this; IIRC the Linux console (TERM=linux) has this too; whereas the `screen` and `tmux` multiplexers (TERM=screen) don't.

See also https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=754596.

I'd love to fix this, but this would require to get buy-in from xterm/ncurses's developer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use spaces on black background until the end of the line.

You may also find useful https://github.com/fazibear/colorize gem, it makes working with ANSI colors much easier.

[image: sample screenshot]

Code on the screenshot:

```
require 'colorize'
# => true
SCREEN_WIDTH = 204
# => 204
puts ('x' * (SCREEN_WIDTH + 1)).white.on_red + (' ' * (SCREEN_WIDTH - 1)) + ('x' * SCREEN_WIDTH).white.on_red
```

Comment: Printing spaces at the end of the line provides an undesired copy-paste experience, as well as undesired resize-on-rewrap (available in newer gnome-terminals than the reporter has) behavior. Moreover, it's subject to race condition (behaves incorrectly if the window is resized between your app queries the window size and prints the spaces). A perhaps better approach (still subject to race, though) is to print the sequence `\e[K` to clear to the end of the line, but this must only be printed if the normal output didn't end at the exact end of the line, otherwise it strips off a character.

Comment: @egmont, thank you for insight. I'm not a pro in this field, just noticed a hack, and wanted to share. Feel free to downvote if you think this will cause more harm than usefulness. Thanks!

Comment: No no, no downvote at all! :) This is a messed up situation to begin with, with no proper solution, only dirty workarounds :)